# Reset ObjectOutPutStream to update new object state?

Tags: java, reset, objectoutputstream

I want to reset ObjectOutPutStream to update the new object state. But why it doesn't effect. The below code outputs "BEFORE" instead of "AFTER"? What's wrong with my code?

```
package test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Serialization {
    public static void main(String[] strs) {
        String filename = "E:\\myObject.data";

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        try {

            myObject.setValue("BEFORE");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(myObject);
            out.reset();
            myObject.setValue("AFTER");
            out.writeObject(myObject);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            ObjectInputStream in = null;
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            myObject = (MyObject) in.readObject();
            System.out.println(myObject.getValue());
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class MyObject implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5222199410120362372L;
        private String value;

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing two copies of an object but only reading one.  If you read two objects you will see BEFORE and AFTER.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I am confused with the explanation in this article http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/ (at "Caching Objects in the Stream" )

Comment: Try the same test without the reset() and you will see the difference.

Comment: The Sea.. your link is broken. Is [this](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-07-2000/jw-0714-flatten.html?page=5) the same article you are referring to?

Comment: Actually this [link](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue088.html) is quite a good read on the subject too. The author  performance test different approaches of using ObjectOutputStream. Sadly though, he miss to test the writeUnshared method and another yet another approach which would be to create a new ObjectOutputStream instead of just reseting the cache.